# Same NodeJS Version across multiple stages in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration

How to use the same `node version` across multiple stages in a `debian node` in jenkins?

```js
node('debian') {
  sh """
    source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh &> /dev/null
    nvm install 8 &> /dev/null
    npm install yarn -g --silent

    node --version # correct 8
    yarn --version # correct 1.6.*
  """

  timestamps {
    ansiColor('xterm') {

      stage('Prepare') {
        sh """
          node --version # wrong 6.11
          yarn --version # wrong 1.12
        """
      }

      stage('Build') {
        sh """
          node --version # wrong 6.11
          yarn --version # wrong 1.2
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I reeaaallly hate to be that guy, but....

Have you considered the [Jenkins Node.js Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs)? This plugin lets you declare multiple versions of Node.js Jenkins tools, and then gives you some pipeline syntax to select the Node version + even an npmrc file for when you need to specify registry or something.

Example snippet from Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  steps {
    nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'MY_NODEJS_TOOL_NAME_HERE', configId: 'ID_OF_THE_CONFIG_FILE') {
      sh "node --version" // should be correct
    }
  }
}
```

As to why your nvm isn't working, I suspect (but it's almost entirely speculation) that `nvm` is playing games with your `PATH`, but when the `sh` block ends so does the cleverly reset path. Thus when you try to use your Node version in another `sh` call, `PATH` is back to what it was before.